# use an array of google places types

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

i'm programmaticaly trying to set dynamicaly the types of the places i want to search , i have an array selectedPlaceTypes filled as follows :  ["aquarium", " art_gallery", " bar"] . only one type in the array is taken into account .

```
 var request = {
            location: pos,
            radius: 5000,
            types: selectedPlaceTypes
          };
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
          service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation, it says: `types — Restricts the results to Places matching at least one of the specified types. Types should be separated with a pipe symbol (type1|type2|etc).` So use `var types="aquarium|art_gallery|bar"` .

Or maybe the problem is just the spaces you have in `art_gallery` and `bar`

Comment: the problem was the white spaces indeed , so all i had to do is to remove'em and assign the array directly to types (it can take a dynamic array of types)

Comment: @FrozenFlame Yeah I guessed it could be that, but looked into the api just in case. Glad it worked!